# Discover long patterns

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a sorted list of numbers, I would like to find the longest subsequence where the differences between successive elements are geometrically increasing.  So if the list is

```
 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 15, 27, 30, 31, 81
```

then the subsequence is `1, 3, 7, 15, 31`.  Alternatively consider `1, 2, 5, 6, 11, 15, 23, 41, 47` which has subsequence `5, 11, 23, 47` with a = 3 and k = 2.

Can this be solved in O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time? Where n is the length of the list.

I am interested both in the general case where the progression of differences is *ak*, *ak*<sup>2</sup>, *ak*<sup>3</sup>, etc., where both *a* and *k* are integers, and in the special case where *a* = 1, so the progression of difference is *k*, *k*<sup>2</sup>, *k*<sup>3</sup>, etc.

Comment: Are there any bounds on which the sub-sequences start or increase by?

Comment: Well I am stumped, there are O(N^2) starting points for a subsequence, since any pair could start it.

Comment: Is the list always sorted?

Comment: @kol Yes it is always sorted.

Comment: Can the common ratio of the geometric progression of differences be any real number? Or are these integers? For example, the series [1, 2.5, 4.75] has the gaps [1.5, 2.25], which is geometric with ratio 1.5.

Comment: @kol The common ratio should be an integer.

Comment: I can come up with an `O(N^2lg(N))` dynamic programming solution with `O(N^2)` memory immediately but can't reduce it further to O(N^2) As @Guvante has already stated, there will be O(N^2) starting pair, so it can be proved that it can't be solved in `O(N^2)` time

Comment: @Fallen, why not post it as an answer? Your algorithm will be interesting in its own right, without compromising the OP's question. And it may invite better solutions.

Comment: @MihaiDanila: OP specifies s/he needs the solution with O(N^2) time. So there's a chance s/he already knows the solution of runtime `O(N^2lgN)` :)

Comment: @Fallen Other people who find the question via google might not know the solution. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @kqr: Though perhaps they should take some pen and paper and try to figure it out by themselves. The posted time complexity is surely a big hint.

Comment: Does the subsequence have to be a geometric series (`k^1,k^2,...`)? Or can the differences be `k^1,k^3,k^4,...`?

Comment: @Jacob The example shows that the *differences* follow a geometric progression. The differences for 1, 3, 7, 15, 31 are 2, 4, 8, 16, where both the scale factor (= the first item) and the common ratio are 2.

Comment: @kol: Sorry, that's what I meant. I wanted to see if the differences had to start from `k^1,k^2,...` as opposed to an arbitrary `k^3,k^4,k^10,...`.

Comment: aren't there infinite possible common ratios to test?

Comment: @groovy: No. The ratio is bounded by a function of the difference between the last and first element.

Comment: @Jacob's question is key here, I think.  I believe there is an `n^2` algorithm if the progression of differences must look like (`k`, `k^2`, `k^3`...), but that there is a lower bound of `n^3` if it may look like (`a*k`, `a*k^2`, `a*k^3`).  The example is of the first form, so it's not clear.

Comment: I suggest adding " The common ratio should be an integer. " to the description of the problem. Also, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), a geometric progression is defined `ar^0, ar^1, ar^2, ...`. Is `a` always 1 in your case, or can it be an arbitrary real number, or integer?

Comment: @AaronDufour. I am interested in both cases. Thank you pointing out the difference between them.

Comment: Do you consider k=1 a valid solution?

Comment: @jbaylina yes k=1 is valid although that is an easier case.

Comment: What are the values of a, k for the second example? It seems to me this example is invalid if a should be an integer.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer a=3 and k = 2. I included k^0.

Comment: @felix This contradicts your last paragraph. First element should be ``a`` then.

Comment: To be consistent with the a=1 case I changed the example. Thank you. It might be nice to include a in the sequence when a > 1 however.

Comment: What is limitations for numbers and count?

Comment: @Толя A solution that worked for lists of up to length 100000 and values up to 10 million would be great.

Comment: @felix The initial array is a list of integers or are reals?

Comment: @jbaylina They will be integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

I have made an improvement of the algorithm that it takes an average of O(M + N^2) and memory needs of O(M+N). Mainly is the same that the protocol described below, but to calculate the possible factors A,K for ech diference D, I preload a table. This table takes less than a second to be constructed for M=10^7.

I have made a C implementation that takes less than 10minutes to solve N=10^5 diferent random integer elements.

Here is the source code in C: To execute just do: gcc -O3 -o findgeo findgeo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Factor {
    int a;
    int k;
    struct Factor *next;
};

struct Factor *factors = 0;
int factorsL=0;

void ConstructFactors(int R) {
    int a,k,C;
    int R2;
    struct Factor *f;
    float seconds;
    clock_t end;
    clock_t start = clock();

    if (factors) free(factors);
    factors = malloc (sizeof(struct Factor) *((R>>1) + 1));
    R2 = R>>1 ;
    for (a=0;a<=R2;a++) {
        factors[a].a= a;
        factors[a].k=1;
        factors[a].next=NULL;
    }
    factorsL=R2+1;
    R2 = floor(sqrt(R));
    for (k=2; k<=R2; k++) {
        a=1;
        C=a*k*(k+1);
        while (C<R) {
            C >>= 1;
            f=malloc(sizeof(struct Factor));
            *f=factors[C];
            factors[C].a=a;
            factors[C].k=k;
            factors[C].next=f;
            a++;
            C=a*k*(k+1);
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Construct Table: %f\n",seconds);
}

void DestructFactors() {
    int i;
    struct Factor *f;
    for (i=0;i<factorsL;i++) {
        while (factors[i].next) {
            f=factors[i].next->next;
            free(factors[i].next);
            factors[i].next=f;
        }
    }
    free(factors);
    factors=NULL;
    factorsL=0;
}

int ipow(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (exp)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}

void findGeo(int **bestSolution, int *bestSolutionL,int *Arr, int L) {
    int i,j,D;
    int mustExistToBeBetter;
    int R=Arr[L-1]-Arr[0];
    int *possibleSolution;
    int possibleSolutionL=0;
    int exp;
    int NextVal;
    int idx;
    int kMax,aMax;
    float seconds;
    clock_t end;
    clock_t start = clock();


    kMax = floor(sqrt(R));
    aMax = floor(R/2);
    ConstructFactors(R);
    *bestSolutionL=2;
    *bestSolution=malloc(0);

    possibleSolution = malloc(sizeof(int)*(R+1));

    struct Factor *f;
    int *H=malloc(sizeof(int)*(R+1));
    memset(H,0, sizeof(int)*(R+1));
    for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
        H[ Arr[i]-Arr[0] ]=1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<L-2;i++) {
        for (j=i+2; j<L; j++) {
            D=Arr[j]-Arr[i];
            if (D & 1) continue;
            f = factors + (D >>1);
            while (f) {
                idx=Arr[i] + f->a * f->k  - Arr[0];
                if ((f->k <= kMax)&& (f->a<aMax)&&(idx<=R)&&H[idx]) {
                    if (f->k ==1) {
                        mustExistToBeBetter = Arr[i] + f->a * (*bestSolutionL);
                    } else {
                        mustExistToBeBetter = Arr[i] + f->a * f->k * (ipow(f->k,*bestSolutionL) - 1)/(f->k-1);
                    }
                    if (mustExistToBeBetter< Arr[L-1]+1) {
                        idx=  floor(mustExistToBeBetter - Arr[0]);
                    } else {
                        idx = R+1;
                    }
                    if ((idx<=R)&&H[idx]) {
                        possibleSolution[0]=Arr[i];
                        possibleSolution[1]=Arr[i] + f->a*f->k;
                        possibleSolution[2]=Arr[j];
                        possibleSolutionL=3;
                        exp = f->k * f->k * f->k;
                        NextVal = Arr[j] + f->a * exp;
                        idx=NextVal - Arr[0];
                        while ( (idx<=R) && H[idx]) {
                            possibleSolution[possibleSolutionL]=NextVal;
                            possibleSolutionL++;
                            exp = exp * f->k;
                            NextVal = NextVal + f->a * exp;
                            idx=NextVal - Arr[0];
                        }

                        if (possibleSolutionL > *bestSolutionL) {
                            free(*bestSolution);
                            *bestSolution = possibleSolution;
                            possibleSolution = malloc(sizeof(int)*(R+1));
                            *bestSolutionL=possibleSolutionL;
                            kMax= floor( pow (R, 1/ (*bestSolutionL) ));
                            aMax= floor(R /  (*bestSolutionL));
                        }
                    }
                }
                f=f->next;
            }
        }
    }

    if (*bestSolutionL == 2) {
        free(*bestSolution);
        possibleSolutionL=0;
        for (i=0; (i<2)&&(i<L); i++ ) {
            possibleSolution[possibleSolutionL]=Arr[i];
            possibleSolutionL++;
        }
        *bestSolution = possibleSolution;
        *bestSolutionL=possibleSolutionL;
    } else {
        free(possibleSolution);
    }
    DestructFactors();
    free(H);

    end = clock();
    seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("findGeo: %f\n",seconds);
}

int compareInt (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}

int main(void) {
    int N=100000;
    int R=10000000;
    int *A = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    int *Sol;
    int SolL;
    int i;


    int *S=malloc(sizeof(int)*R);
    for (i=0;i<R;i++) S[i]=i+1;

    for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
        int r = rand() % (R-i);
        A[i]=S[r];
        S[r]=S[R-i-1];
    }

    free(S);
    qsort(A,N,sizeof(int),compareInt);

/*
    int step = floor(R/N);
    A[0]=1;
    for (i=1;i<N;i++) {
        A[i]=A[i-1]+step;
    }
*/

    findGeo(&Sol,&SolL,A,N);

    printf("[");
    for (i=0;i<SolL;i++) {
        if (i>0) printf(",");
        printf("%d",Sol[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
    printf("Size: %d\n",SolL);

    free(Sol);
    free(A);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Demostration**

I will try to demonstrate that the algorithm that I proposed is [image: O(N`2+M)] in average for an equally distributed random sequence. I’m not a mathematician and I am not used to do this kind of demonstrations, so please fill free to correct me any error that you can see.

There are 4 indented loops, the two firsts are the N^2 factor.  The M is for the calculation of the possible factors table).

The third loop is executed only once in average for each pair. You can see this checking the size of the pre-calculated factors table. It’s size is M when N->inf. So the average steps for each pair is M/M=1.

So the proof happens to check that the forth loop. (The one that traverses the good made sequences is executed less that or equal O(N^2) for all the pairs.

To demonstrate that, I will consider two cases: one where M>>N and  other where M ~= N. Where M is the maximum difference of the initial array: M= S(n)-S(1).

For the first case, (M>>N) the probability to find a coincidence is p=N/M. To start a sequence, it must coincide the second and the b+1 element where b is the length of the best sequence until now. So the loop will enter [image: N^2*(N/M)^2] times. And the average length of this series (supposing an infinite series) is  [image: p/(1-p) = N/(M-N)]. So the total number of times that the loop will be executed is [image: N^2 * (N/M)^2 * N/(M-N)]. And this is close to 0 when M>>N.  The problem here is when M~=N.

Now lets consider this case where M~=N. Lets consider that b is the best sequence length until now. For the case A=k=1, then the sequence must start before N-b, so the number of sequences will be N-b, and the times that will go for the loop will be a maximum of (N-b)*b.

For A>1 and k=1 we can extrapolate to [image: (N-A*b/d)*b] where d is M/N (the average distance between numbers).  If we add for all A’s from 1 to dN/b then we see a top limit of:

[image: \sum_{A=1}^{dN/b}\left ( N-\frac{Ab}{d} \right )b=\frac{N^2d}{2}]

For the cases where k>=2, we see that the sequence must start before [image: N-A*k^b/d], So the loop will enter an average of [image: A*k^b/d)*b] and adding for all As from 1 to dN/k^b, it gives a limit of

[image: \sum_{A=1}^{dN/k^b}\left ( N-\frac{Ak^b}{d} \right )b=\frac{bN^2d}{2k^b}]

Here,  the worst case is when b is minimum. Because we are considering minimum series, lets consider a very worst case of  b= 2 so the number of passes for the 4th loop for a given k will be less than

[image: \frac{dN^2}{k^2}] .

And if we add all k’s from 2 to infinite will be:

[image: \sum_{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{dN^2}{k^2} = dN^2 \left ( \frac{\pi ^2}{6} -1\right )]

So adding  all the passes for k=1 and k>=2, we have a maximum of:

[image: \frac{N^2d}{2} +N^2d \left ( \frac{\pi ^2}{6} -1\right ) = N^2d\left ( \frac{\pi ^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\right ) \simeq 1.45N^2d]

Note that d=M/N=1/p.

So we have two limits, One that goes to infinite when d=1/p=M/N goes to 1 and other that goes to infinite when d goes to infinite. So our limit is the minimum of both, and the worst case is when both equetions cross. So if we solve the equation:

[image: N^2d\left ( \frac{\pi ^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\right ) = N^2\left ( \frac{N}{M} \right )^2\frac{N}{M-N} =N^2\left ( \frac{1}{d} \right )^2\frac{1}{d-1}]

we see that the maximum is when d=1.353

So it is demonstrated that the forth loops will be processed less than 1.55N^2 times in total.

Of course, this is for the average case. For the worst case I am not able to find a way to generate series whose forth loop are higher than O(N^2), and I strongly believe that they does not exist, but I am not a mathematician to prove it.

**Old Answer**

Here is a solution in average of O((n^2)*cube_root(M)) where M is the difference between the first and last element of the array. And memory requirements of O(M+N).

1.- Construct an array H of length M so that M[i - S[0]]=true if i exists in the initial array and false if it does not exist.

2.- For each pair in the array S[j], S[i] do:

2.1 Check if it can be the first and third elements of a possible solution. To do so, calculate all possible A,K pairs that meet the equation S(i) = S(j) + AK + AK^2. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286012/given-a-natural-number-a-i-want-to-find-all-the-pairs-of-natural-numbers-b-c) to see how to solve this problem. And check that exist the second element: S[i]+ A*K

2.2 Check also that exist the element one position further that the best solution that we have. For example, if the best solution that we have until now is 4 elements long then check that exist the element A[j] + A*K + A*K^2 + A*K^3 + A*K^4

2.3 If 2.1 and 2.2 are true, then iterate how long is this series and set as the bestSolution until now is is longer that the last.

Here is the code in javascript:

```
function getAKs(A) {
    if (A / 2 != Math.floor(A / 2)) return [];
    var solution = [];
    var i;
    var SR3 = Math.pow(A, 1 / 3);
    for (i = 1; i <= SR3; i++) {
        var B, C;
        C = i;
        B = A / (C * (C + 1));
        if (B == Math.floor(B)) {
            solution.push([B, C]);
        }

        B = i;
        C = (-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 4 * A / B)) / 2;
        if (C == Math.floor(C)) {
            solution.push([B, C]);
        }
    }

    return solution;
}

function getBestGeometricSequence(S) {
    var i, j, k;

    var bestSolution = [];

    var H = Array(S[S.length-1]-S[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++) H[S[i] - S[0]] = true;

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            var PossibleAKs = getAKs(S[i] - S[j]);
            for (k = 0; k < PossibleAKs.length; k++) {
                var A = PossibleAKs[k][0];
                var K = PossibleAKs[k][17];

                var mustExistToBeBetter;
                if (K==1) {
                    mustExistToBeBetter = S[j] + A * bestSolution.length;
                } else {
                    mustExistToBeBetter = S[j] + A * K * (Math.pow(K,bestSolution.length) - 1)/(K-1);
                }

                if ((H[S[j] + A * K - S[0]]) && (H[mustExistToBeBetter - S[0]])) {
                    var possibleSolution=[S[j],S[j] + A * K,S[i]];
                    exp = K * K * K;
                    var NextVal = S[i] + A * exp;
                    while (H[NextVal - S[0]] === true) {
                        possibleSolution.push(NextVal);
                        exp = exp * K;
                        NextVal = NextVal + A * exp;
                    }

                    if (possibleSolution.length > bestSolution.length) {
                        bestSolution = possibleSolution;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestSolution;
}

//var A= [ 1, 2, 3,5,7, 15, 27, 30,31, 81];
var A=[];
for (i=1;i<=3000;i++) {
    A.push(i);
}
var sol=getBestGeometricSequence(A);

$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(sol));
```

You can check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/6yHyR/1/

I maintain the other solution because I believe that it is still better when M is very big compared to N.

Comment: `while (H[NextVal] === true) { ... }` this is not constant time. In the worst case 1, 2, 3, ..., N and k = 1 , it's O(N). In your function `getAKs` the worse case for A^(1/3) is R^(1/3) where R is the range last element minus first. Overall time complexity is O(N * N * R^(1/3) * N) = O(N^3 * R^(1/3) )

Comment: H[NextVal] is in average O(1). Any way, it is a simple search. Use the search algorithm that you want ;)

Comment: I changed the definition of R in the answer. Depending of the array, you can substitute the R^(1/3) by precalculating a table with a cost O(R^(4/3)) and size O(N^2). So the algorithm would be O(R^(4/3)+N^2) in average. Or if bsearch is used: O(R^(4/3)+N^2*log(N)) as a maximum.

Comment: If I had a book that collected algorithms and code worth studying, this answer and the other one I read by you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871113/how-to-match-dna-sequence-pattern/16903109#16903109) would be in it. Nice work.

Comment: This looks to be a reasonable algorithm, but it's certainly not O(n^2 * m^(1/3)) as claimed, for exactly the reason @darksky gave: the innermost extension loop can take O(n) time, making it O(n^3 * m^(1/3)) overall. -1 for now, +2 when this claim is corrected.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I changed the hash table lookup for a simple table lookup with constant access time ( O(1) ) (It was already done in the C code). Of Course it now is O(M+N) memory size instead of O(N). The improvement already uses a lookup table instead of a hash, and it is an O(M+N^2) algorithm and needs O(M+N) memory. The size of the  precalculated factors is allways less than M.

Comment: @jbaylina: It's not the hash lookup that I'm concerned about, it's the innermost extension loop -- the one starting with `while ( (idx<=R) && H[idx]) {` in your C version.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It is impossible to find a "pathological"serie that this loop is executed more than 3*N^2 times in total (Adding all the times this loop is executed). So the Algorithm is O(N^2)+O(3*N^2) = O(N^2). If you try to generate this pathological serie, you will see why.

Comment: @jbaylina: darksky already told you the pathological input: it's simply 1, 2, 3, ..., N and k = 1!

Comment: @j_random_hacker With this serie, it is executed only N times becouse when i>2, the BestSolution=N and it does not enter the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  I think that test will eliminate a lot of pointless calculation, but I'm still not convinced it will eliminate enough in every case: I think it might be possible to craft a sequence so that it still takes much worse than the advertised time complexity, though I might not be smart enough to craft such a sequence ;) I've dropped my -1 for the time being, but no +1 till you can *prove* the advertised time complexity!

Comment: I don't understand why this would be O(N^2+M) time. It seems from your description you look at every pair of indices and for each one do a potentially non constant amount of work in 2.3.  Can you explain more why you think the total work done by all N^2 applications of step 2.3  is only O(N^2) ?

Comment: @user2179021 I have inserted a first aproach to the demostration.

Comment: I would be worried about an algorithm that scales with `M`.  There's no reason to believe that `M` is bounded (beyond memory concerns, of course, but scaling exponentially with the amount of memory on the machine doesn't seem like a good idea, either).

Comment: @AaronDufour It grows linealy by M (The memorory and the time). If M grows very much, then there are alternatives in O(N^3) or even less. You can also change the lookup table with for a Hash table. I precisely didn't delete an old answer with an algorithm that performs much better for very high M values. Take in account also that very high M values also implies that simple operations takes longer than O(1). I have tried to adapt the protocol to N=10^5 M=10^7 (Because one comment of the question's author).

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I would expect `O(n^3)` to perform better than anything that scales with `M` on real data sets, in the absence of other information.  Since the question discusses this in terms of `n`, it seems safe to assume that `M` is unbounded.  Do you have an example of a solution that scales only to `N` (or at least to no more than `log(M)`, which is reasonable for unbounded `M`)?

Answer (score 1):

Just to start with something, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/futxL/14/) is a simple solution in JavaScript:

```
var input = [0.7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 15, 27, 30, 31, 81], 
    output = [], indexes, values, i, index, value, i_max_length,
    i1, i2, i3, j1, j2, j3, difference12a, difference23a, difference12b, difference23b,
    scale_factor, common_ratio_a, common_ratio_b, common_ratio_c,
    error, EPSILON = 1e-9, common_ratio_is_integer,
    resultDiv = $("#result");

for (i1 = 0; i1 < input.length - 2; ++i1) {
    for (i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < input.length - 1; ++i2) {
        scale_factor = difference12a = input[i2] - input[i1];
        for (i3 = i2 + 1; i3 < input.length; ++i3) {
            difference23a = input[i3] - input[i2];
            common_ratio_1a = difference23a / difference12a;
            common_ratio_2a = Math.round(common_ratio_1a);
            error = Math.abs((common_ratio_2a - common_ratio_1a) / common_ratio_1a);
            common_ratio_is_integer = error < EPSILON;
            if (common_ratio_2a > 1 && common_ratio_is_integer) {
                indexes = [i1, i2, i3];
                j1 = i2;
                j2 = i3
                difference12b = difference23a;
                for (j3 = j2 + 1; j3 < input.length; ++j3) {
                    difference23b = input[j3] - input[j2];
                    common_ratio_1b = difference23b / difference12b;
                    common_ratio_2b = Math.round(common_ratio_1b);
                    error = Math.abs((common_ratio_2b - common_ratio_1b) / common_ratio_1b);
                    common_ratio_is_integer = error < EPSILON;
                    if (common_ratio_is_integer && common_ratio_2a === common_ratio_2b) {
                        indexes.push(j3);
                        j1 = j2;
                        j2 = j3
                        difference12b = difference23b;
                    }
                }
                values = [];
                for (i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
                    index = indexes[i];
                    value = input[index];
                    values.push(value);
                }
                output.push(values);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (output !== []) {
    i_max_length = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < output.length; ++i) {
        if (output[i_max_length].length < output[i].length)
            i_max_length = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < output.length; ++i) {
        if (output[i_max_length].length == output[i].length)
            resultDiv.append("<p>[" + output[i] + "]</p>");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 7, 15, 31]
```

I find the first three items of every subsequence candidate, calculate the scale factor and the common ratio from them, and if the common ratio is integer, then I iterate over the remaining elements after the third one, and add those to the subsequence, which fit into the geometric progression defined by the first three items. As a last step, I select the sebsequence/s which has/have the largest length.

Comment: Your analysis seems to be off. What happens when you give it an input of consecutive integers like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 100]?

Comment: Sorry, I meant your O(N^3) complexity analysis. If you allow a common_ratio of 1, it takes O(N^4) for my test case. If you require common_ratio > 1, then it takes O(N^3 log N).

Comment: @arghbleargh You are right, my analysis was wrong. I deleted my speed estimate from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is exactly the same question as [Longest equally-spaced subsequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159911/longest-equally-spaced-subsequence), you just have to consider the logarithm of your data. If the sequence is *a, ak, ak^2, ak^3*, the logarithmique value is *ln(a), ln(a) + ln(k), ln(a)+2ln(k), ln(a)+3ln(k)*, so it is equally spaced. The opposite is of course true. There is a lot of different code in the question above.

I don't think the special case a=1 can be resolved more efficiently than an adaptation from an algorithm above.

Comment: As far as I understand, OP wants to find longest sequence which looks like like `start, start + a * k, start + a * k^2, start + a * k^3`. Could you clarify how do you find it with your logarithmic approach? You could use sequence `1, 2, 5, 6, 11, 15, 23, 41, 47` as example

Comment: Do you take the log of each number of the array (N numbers) or take the log of the differences: (N^2/2-N). Converting a geometrical to lineal, seems a good idea, but I can't realy see how the algorithm would work. Please, explain the example.

Comment: @RomanPekar It's more like `start, start + ak, start + ak + ak^2, start + ak + ak^2 + ak^3, ...`

Comment: It would be equivalent for a serie of the kind, start , start*k , start*k^2,start*k^3. But that's not the definition of the problem. For me this answer is a -1 unless some convincing explanation that I can't see is given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Javascript. It should be close to O(n^2) except may be in some pathological cases.

```
function bsearch(Arr,Val, left,right) {
    if (left == right) return left;
    var m=Math.floor((left + right) /2);
    if (Val <= Arr[m]) {
        return bsearch(Arr,Val,left,m);
    } else {
        return bsearch(Arr,Val,m+1,right);
    }
}

function findLongestGeometricSequence(S) {
    var bestSolution=[];

    var i,j,k;
    var H={};
    for (i=0;i<S.length;i++) H[S[i]]=true;

    for (i=0;i<S.length;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<i;j++) {
            for (k=j+1;k<i;) {
                var possibleSolution=[S[j],S[k],S[i]];

                var K = (S[i] - S[k]) / (S[k] - S[j]);
                var A = (S[k] - S[j]) * (S[k] - S[j]) / (S[i] - S[k]); 

                if ((Math.floor(K) == K) && (Math.floor(A)==A)) {
                    exp= K*K*K;
                    var NextVal= S[i] + A * exp;
                    while (H[NextVal] === true) {
                        possibleSolution.push(NextVal);
                        exp = exp * K;
                        NextVal= NextVal + A * exp;                
                    }

                    if (possibleSolution.length > bestSolution.length)
                        bestSolution=possibleSolution;

                    K--;
                } else {
                    K=Math.floor(K);
                }

                if (K>0) {
                    var NextPossibleMidValue= (S[i] + K*S[j]) / (K +1); 
                    k++;
                    if (S[k]<NextPossibleMidValue) {
                        k=bsearch(S,NextPossibleMidValue, k+1, i);
                    }
                } else {
                    k=i;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    return bestSolution;
}


function Run() {
    var MyS= [0.7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7, 15, 27, 30,31, 81];

    var sol = findLongestGeometricSequence(MyS); 

    alert(JSON.stringify(sol));
}
```

**Small Explanation**

If we take 3 numbers of the array S(j) < S(k) < S(i) then you can calculate a and k so that: S(k) = S(j) + a*k and S(i) = S(k) + a*k^2 (2 equations and 2 incognits). With that in mind, you can check if exist a number in the array that is S(next) = S(i) + a*k^3. If that is the case, then continue checknng for S(next2) = S(next) + a*k^4 and so on.

This would be a O(n^3) solution, but you can hava advantage that k must be integer in order to limit the S(k) points selected.

In case that a is known, then you can calculate a(k) and you need to check only one number in the third loop, so this case will be clearly a O(n^2).

Comment: I'm getting `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` when I run this code. That is an invalid result.

Comment: 2 = 1 + 1*1;
3 = 2 + 1*1^2;
4 = 3 + 1*1^3;
Do you accept k=1? In the algo I accept any value for a (not only integer) It can be changed easyly.

Comment: Hah. Not sure if k=1 is called geometric. I think OP is referring to k >= 2.

Comment: To accept only k>1 and integer a change the if (Math.floor(K) == K) with this condition: if ((Math.floor(K) == K)&&(Math.floor(A) ==A)&&(K>1))

Comment: If a=1 then S(k) can be calculated and then it is clearly a O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: I like your idea of computing a and k. Can you please explain your `nextPossibleMidValue` formula? Why don't you just do `H[S[i]] = i` so you don't have to binary-search for it? You could just look it up constant time like `k=H[nextPossibleMidValue]`. Also, as is, this isn't n^2 because of this binary search inside the two loops.

Comment: I try to find the S[k] with the next possible k. This is done by solving the same equation system, but now the incognits are A and S[k].

Comment: I could do it what you propose: do the check, and if it does not exist, just decrement k, but doing my way you can decrement k much faster. Imagine this sequence: [1,2,30000,65001] a[j]=1; a[i]=65001, I don't want to test for k=65000, k=64999, k=64998, ....

Comment: I agree that it is a little more that O(n^2) for a beeing a variable.

Comment: I just added the condition for A beeing an integer, and also to do the b search only when the next S[k] is less than the nextPossibleMidValue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this task is related with not so long ago posted [Longest equally-spaced subsequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159911/longest-equally-spaced-subsequence). I've just modified my algorithm in Python a little bit:

```
from math import sqrt

def add_precalc(precalc, end, (a, k), count, res, N):
    if end + a * k ** res[1]["count"] > N: return

    x = end + a * k ** count
    if x > N or x < 0: return

    if precalc[x] is None: return

    if (a, k) not in precalc[x]:
        precalc[x][(a, k)] = count

    return

def factors(n):
    res = []
    for x in range(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            y = n / x
            res.append((x, y))
            res.append((y, x))
    return res

def work(input):
    precalc = [None] * (max(input) + 1)
    for x in input: precalc[x] = {}

    N = max(input)

    res = ((0, 0), {"end":0, "count":0})
    for i, x in enumerate(input):
        for y in input[i::-1]:
            for a, k in factors(x - y):
                if (a, k) in precalc[x]: continue
                add_precalc(precalc, x, (a, k), 2, res, N)

        for step, count in precalc[x].iteritems():
            count += 1
            if count > res[1]["count"]: res = (step, {"end":x, "count":count})
            add_precalc(precalc, x, step, count, res, N)
        precalc[x] = None

    d = [res[1]["end"]]
    for x in range(res[1]["count"] - 1, 0, -1):
        d.append(d[-1] - res[0][0] * res[0][1] ** x)
    d.reverse()
    return d
```

**explanation**

- Traversing the array
- For each previous element of the array calculate factors of the difference between current and taken previous element and then precalculate next possible element of the sequence and saving it to precalc array
- So when arriving at element `i` there're already all possible sequences with element `i` in the precalc array, so we have to calculate next possible element and save it to precalc.

Currently there's one place in algorithm that could be slow - factorization of each previous number. I think it could be made faster with two optimizations:

- more effective factorization algorithm
- find a way not to see at each element of array, using the fact that array is sorted and there's already a precalculated sequences

Comment: Does this only work when a=1? Could you add some explanation of the method as well please as code alone is hard to interpret.

Comment: Yes, sorry, had no time to add axplanation. It does work only for a = 1 (I haven't realized that there should be a * k^n and not k^n), so I would modify it later (it's night here already) and will add some explanation

Comment: Looks likes line 3 is redundant. How big is `precalc[x]`? This looks to be `O(N* sizeof(precalc)^2)`, good algorithm though.

Comment: thanks, I have to consider possible size of precalc[x]. It could be made a dictionary instead of array, I have to check which is faster in python. Had absolutely no time today to modify algorithm :(

Comment: A brief human readable paragraph describing what this algorithm is doing would be useful, especially for those who may not be as familiar with Python as you.

Comment: sorry for that, have absolutely no time :( I've added a short explanation and change an algorithm

Comment: It is the same algorithm except for the factorization algorithm. It can be don in O(cube_root(M)) see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286012/given-a-natural-number-a-i-want-to-find-all-the-pairs-of-natural-numbers-b-c I also did the second optimization that you propose by checking that exist the (M+1)th element of the subsequence wuere M is the best sequence that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
def subseq(a):
    seq = []
    aset = set(a)
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        # elements after x
        for j, x2 in enumerate(a[i+1:]):
            j += i + 1  # enumerate starts j at 0, we want a[j] = x2
            bk = x2 - x  # b*k (assuming k and k's exponent start at 1)

            # given b*k, bruteforce values of k
            for k in range(1, bk + 1):
                items = [x, x2]  # our subsequence so far
                nextdist = bk * k # what x3 - x2 should look like

                while items[-1] + nextdist in aset:
                    items.append(items[-1] + nextdist)
                    nextdist *= k

                if len(items) > len(seq):
                    seq = items

    return seq
```

Running time is `O(dn^3)`, where `d` is the (average?) distance between two elements,
and `n` is of course `len(a)`.

Comment: I have no idea. Only the first for-loop has n interations (O(n)), the iterations of the second one decrement by 1 every iteration of the first (O(log n)?), the third one is... dunno and the fourth behaves similar to the second.